# Python math issue

Tags: python-3.x, list, math, while-loop

A geometric progression is a sequence of numbers in which each value (after the first) is obtained by multiplying the previous value in the sequence by a fixed value called the common ratio. For example the sequence `3, 12, 48, 192, ...` is a geometric progression in which the common ratio is `4`.

Given the positive integer ratio greater than 1, and the non-negative integer n, create a list consisting of the geometric progression of numbers between (and including) 1 and n with a common ratio of ratio. For example, if ratio is 2 and n is 8, the list would be `[1, 2, 4, 8]`.

Associate the list with the variable `geom_prog`.

I'm having trouble figuring this out, I'm supposed to use a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you always must include the description of what you have tried so far and what error you encountered while doing so. It is not nice to ask a question directly without showing your efforts in it.

Now coming back to your question, it is actually quite very easy, what you can do is this:

```
temp = 1
geom_prog = []
while temp<n+1:
    geom_prog.append(temp)
    temp = temp*ratio
```

Comment: Thank you, it's my first time on this site. I will make sure to do so the next time if I have any issues.

Comment: Much appreciated, @Anthony. :)